# Urban Airship: Remote Notifications to Ad-hoc Users

Tags: ios, urbanairship.com

I am using Urban Airship for Remote Push Notifications but I am not sure which SSL certificate to use.

If I am conducting beta testing (ad-hoc distribution) with a number of other iPhone devices, should I use the Development Push Certificate or the Production Push Certificate. I have tried both, and neither are working.

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out - it is the production certificate.